# Как в телеграмме(web) пригласить всех пользователей с помощь js?

Tags: javascript, html, веб-программирование

Мне нужно везде галочки поставит, через js в консоли я пробовал, но он ставит почему то галочку одному пользователю

```
<ul class="chatlist">
    <li class="chatlist-chat rp" data-peer-id="1785764985">
    <label class="checkbox-field checkbox-without-caption">
    <input class="checkbox-field-input" type="checkbox">
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
$("ul.chatlist label").click();
```

Как каждого пользователя выделить галочкой?